# Linking to a Large address aware DLL

Tags: windows, dll, memory-management, winapi

Suppose I have a DLL which is built with LARGEADDRESSAWARE linker flag set. Now I have an application dynamically linking to this DLL. Does this make my application LARGEADDRESSAWARE?

If not then, does it make sense to have this flag set for any DLL?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Discussion [here](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/2008-05/msg00515.html) seems to indicate /LARGEADDRESSAWARE has no efefct on DLLs and depends totally on the hosting executable.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the flag must be set on the main executable. So no, it does not make sense to set it on a DLL. (A possible exception might be when the DLL is run using runDll?)