# What to do to make application Large Address Aware?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

I am currently in process of making our application Large Address Aware. As experience has shown, there are some unexpected gotchas when doing so. I create this post to make a complete list of steps which need to be taken.

The development considerations listed in the [AMD Large Address Aware guide](http://web.archive.org/web/20081207054048/http://www.amd.com/us-en/assets/content_type/DownloadableAssets/Expand_Memory_of_32-bit_App_-_Microsoft_4GT-_6204.pdf) provide a good starting point, but are by no means complete:

> The following considerations will help to make sure that the code can handle addresses larger than 2GB:
>
> - Avoid the use of signed pointer arithmetic (I.e. compares and adds)
> - Pointers use all 32-bits. Don’t use Bit31 for something else.
> - Some dll’s will be loaded just under the 2GB boundary. In this case, no consecutive memory can be allocated with VirtualAlloc().
> - Whenever possible, use GlobalMemoryStatusEx() (preferred) or GlobalMemoryStatus() to retrieve memory sizes.

Therefore, the question is: **What is the complete list of things which need to be done when making C++ Win32 native application Large Address Aware?**

Answer (score 28, accepted):

- (obvious) select Support Address Larger than 2 Gigabytes (/LARGEADDRESSAWARE) in the project properties: Linker / System / Enable Large Address
- check all pointer subtractions and verify the result is stored in a type which can contain the possible difference, or replace them with comparisons or other constructs - see [Detect pointer arithmetics because of LARGEADDRESSAWARE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052028/detect-pointer-arithmetics-because-of-largeaddressaware)). Note: pointer comparison should be fine, contrary to AMD advice, there is no reason why it should cause 4 GB issues
- make sure you are not assuming pointers have Bit31 zero, do not attempt to use Bit31 for something else.
- replace all GetCursorPos calls with GetCursorInfo - see [GetCursorPos fails with large addresses](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/381683/getcursorpos-fails-with-large-addresses-in-large-address-aware-32-bit-process-wpf)
- for all assignments into PVOID64 use PtrToPtr64, needed e.g. when using ReadFileScatter, see [ReadFileScatter remark section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365469%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: "Eliminate all pointer substractions" is excessive. Pointers within an single array work perfectly fine.

Comment: @Suma: pointer additions are NOT fine, since pointer additions can overflow when `LARGEADDRESSAWARE` is set.

Comment: in addition: watch out for 3rd party libraries discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288728/

Comment: Need this linker option, /LARGEADDRESSAWARE only be set once, for linking the application EXE, or must it also be set for linking component DLLs as well?

Comment: @DavidM.Miller It seems the flag has no effect on DLL - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927598/linking-to-a-large-address-aware-dll . Just make sure the DLLs you use with the exe really can handle the large addresses.